# Heroku Bundle Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bundle, bundler

So heroku has trouble bundling my app when using the command:

```
$ git push heroku master
```

It is no problem when I bundle locally

```
$ bundle update
```

And I have made commits and added Gemfile and Gemfile.lock
Any idea why I get this error?

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 25, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (22/22), done.
Writing objects: 100% (22/22), 2.65 KiB, done.
Total 22 (delta 16), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.0.pre.5
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
/app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:66:in `block (2 levels) in spawn': command='/app/slug-compiler/lib/../../tmp/buildpacks/ruby/bin/compile /tmp/build_2c5mcld95eb34 /app/tmp/repo.git/.cache' exit_status=0 out='' at=timeout elapsed=900.1125066280365 (Utils::TimeoutError)
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:52:in `loop'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:52:in `block in spawn'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:47:in `popen'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:47:in `spawn'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/buildpack.rb:37:in `block in compile'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/buildpack.rb:35:in `fork'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/buildpack.rb:35:in `compile'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:497:in `block in run_buildpack'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:121:in `log'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:748:in `log'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:496:in `run_buildpack'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:102:in `block in timeout'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:58:in `timeout'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:102:in `rescue in timeout'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:97:in `timeout'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:114:in `block in compile'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:121:in `log'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:748:in `log'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:113:in `compile'
    from /app/slug-compiler/bin/slugc:85:in `block in <main>'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:505:in `block in lock'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/repo_lock.rb:44:in `call'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/repo_lock.rb:44:in `run'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:505:in `lock'
    from /app/slug-compiler/bin/slugc:66:in `<main>'
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:app_name.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:app_name.git'
```

This is my gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'    

gem 'rails'
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
      gem 'less-rails-bootstrap'
      gem 'less-rails'
      gem 'less'
      gem 'therubyracer'
      gem 'jquery-ui-rails' 
      gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
      gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
      gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :development, :test do
      gem 'rspec-rails'
      gem 'factory_girl_rails'
      gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :test do
      gem "email_spec"
      gem 'faker'
      gem 'capybara'
      gem 'guard-rspec'
      gem 'launchy'
end

# Allow æ,ø,å in strings
gem 'magic_encoding'

# Files uploading gem
gem 'carrierwave'

# Spreadsheet parser gem
gem 'roo'

# Calendar Event Export
gem 'icalendar'

# Authentication gems
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_invitable'
gem "cancan"

# Calendar features
gem 'event-calendar', :require => 'event_calendar'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'nested_form'
gem 'ransack'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Any tips on how to solve this error will be much appreciated.

Comment: `heroku logs` will provide more details about the error.

Comment: This is the only information I can retrieve from log
`2013-01-11T11:21:15+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby/rails app`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The production group is missing in your gemfile:

```
 group :production do
   gem 'pg'
 end
```

Heroku does not support `sqlite`, so you can include the obove in your gemfile.
However, I recommend you to use `postgresql` (pg) for development as well. It will avoid keep running into incompatibilities in your app.

**EDIT** - you should also specify the rails version (gem 'rails 3.2.11') and you can remove the ruby line (ruby '1.9.3').

Comment: Add `gem 'thin'` in the `:production` group, too and this is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

If you have another working rails project on heroku try to copy the gemset or simply the Gemfile to your current project and add project specific gems in that Gemfile and try to get it working that way. Hope you get it solved

Comment: Heroku use thin as their webserver that might be problem, I can't see it in your Gemfile